# Unable to add /usr/local/* programs to path

Tags: path, pop-os

I just unpacked android studio into a folder at this location `/usr/local/android-studio`. 
I want to launch `/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` from the terminal by typing `studio.sh` but I can't seem to achieve this when android-studio is located in `/usr/local/`. 
 It launches just fine if I type the full path in the terminal. 
Am I doing something wrong or is there something special about this folder?

Screenshot for context:
[image: why1]

For now I just moved android studio to the /opt/ directory and there everything works just fine. I just don't understand ***what's so special about the /usr/local folder***.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

> what's so special about the /usr/local folder.

There's nothing special about it - it depends on how your `PATH` variable is set. And that depends on the defaults for your system, which, if nobody has modified it, depends on he defaults of your distribution. So do

```
echo $PATH
```

and have a look at what it contains. If you want to customise it to include `/usr/local/android-studio/bin/`, then find the start up file for your shell (e.g. `~/.profile` for most shells), and have a look at it. If it already sets the path, modify it, otherwise add something like

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/android-studio/bin/
export PATH
```

And BTW, the recommended way for `/usr/local` is to mirror "main" hierarchy, so there's `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib` etc. So it's likely you already **have** `/usr/local/bin` in your path (just not `/usr/local/android-studio/bin`.

And if you have to put stuff in its own subdirectory (as in `/usr/local/android-studio/`), then you make symlinks from `/usr/local/bin` and everywhere else where you need it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio.sh
```

Also have a look at `man stow` how to automate that.